# How can I display a string in a cell from a function returning a double

Tags: vba, excel

I've got a very simple VBA function that takes two range arguments and returns a double using the values of the two ranges. I'm using this in the formula bar of a single cell, but I'm wanting to return a string error should something not be quite right. Is there a way I can show this without it showing *#VALUE* in the cell?

```
Public Function CPP(aPreviousPercentage As Range, aCurrentPercentage As Range) As Double

    If (aPreviousPercentage.Value > 0.2) Then
        CPP = "Invalid Starting Value"
        Exit Function
    End If

    CPP = aCurrentPercentage.Value - aPreviousPercentage.Value

End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the best way to do this is change the return type to variant instead of double. That way if you'd like you can set it to a string instead of a numeric value.

```
Public Function CPP(aPreviousPercentage As Range, aCurrentPercentage As Range) As Variant
```

Comment: Thank you once again! I've just stumbled upon that solution myself and was about to post the answer. :)